# No minions matched the target. No command was sent, no jid was assigned<Salt-stack>

Tags: salt-stack

I installed saltstack and added one minion to master. I get the command output as below

```
$ salt-key
Accepted Keys:
xxxx.abcd.com
Denied Keys:
Unaccepted Keys:
Rejected Keys:
```

but when I hit the

```
$salt \* test.ping
```

command. I get response as

**No response from minion**

Not very sure what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this:

seems that minion was having an old copy of the public key of master and hence handshake was not happening. 
steps of resolution:

```
1. go to folder /etc/salt/pki/minion/ on minion
2. remove master_public file
3. restart the minion
```

now test.ping responds as required

Answer (score 2):

These are two issues with different reasons.

**1**

```
No minions matched the target. No command was sent, no jid was assigned.
```

This happens when you targeted minions which are not registered on the master.

In other words, none of the minions is listed under `Accepted Keys:` of `salt-key` command output.

**2**

```
No response from minion
```

This happens when you targeted minions which are registered but they do not respond.

Comment: Yes you are correct. For me it was the later case where minion was not responding due to mismatch of public keys of master at the minion end